# 経由 - how would I use this in a sentence?

Tags: words, particle-で, sentence

While learning vocab using the kanji 由、I came across the word 経由 which is translated on jisho.org as:

> *Adverbial noun*
>   1. through; by way of; via​
>
> *Suru verb*
>   2. to go via; to go by way of​

This left me confused as to the difference between this word and the particle で and whether it can be replaced by or used with this particle. If anyone could enlighten me to a context in which this word would be used and a few sentence examples, I would be very grateful!

Comment: This may be helpful: http://jisho.org/search/%E7%B5%8C%E7%94%B1%20%23sentences and https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/経由 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

経由 directly follows a noun representing a place and works like a **no-adjective** as a whole.

- 東京駅経由の電車に乗る。
- 上野駅に東京駅経由で行った。
- この電車は東京駅経由です。
- 東京駅経由なら安くなります。

And it works as a prefix-like noun meaning "intermediate" or "transit (point)".

- 経由地
- 経由点
- 経由駅

It also works as a suru-verb meaning "to go through/via ～". It takes を.

- 東京駅を経由して上野に向かいます。
- 東京駅を経由します。

You can ask a transit point like this:

- どこを経由して行きますか？　どの駅を経由して行きますか？
- どこ経由で行きますか？ 何駅経由で行きますか？ (less formal)